# Why isn't the script reading the variable data from %SetWidth% and %SetHeight% Correctly?

Tags: autohotkey

When I replace these with numbers, the script works fine. But to simplify things, I wanted to define a couple variables at the top of the script (SetWidth and SetHeight) and call them as needed throughout. Except, for some reason when I try to call them, it doesn't seem to be working correctly.

```
#NoTrayIcon
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

SetWidth = 1616
SetHeight = 939

Run, ".\full throttle remastered.bat"
Process, Wait, throttle.exe, 120
Process, Exist, throttle.exe
Throttle = %ErrorLevel%
if Throttle != 0
{
    Sleep, 2000
    CenterWindow("ahk_exe throttle.exe")
}
else
{
    MsgBox "Full Throttle Remastered could not be started"
}
return

; The following function centers the specified window on the screen if not already centered:
CenterWindow(WinTitle)
{
    WinGetPos,xx,yy, winx, winy, %WinTitle%
    x1 := xx + winx/2
    y1 := yy + winy/2
    loop 2
    { 
    y1 := yy + winy/2
        loop 2
        { 
            if ((A_ScreenWidth/2 = x1) && (A_ScreenHeight/2 = y1) && (winx = %SetWidth%) && (winy = %SetHeight%)) 
            {
                msgbox got em
            return
            }
            else
            y1 := y1 + 0.5
        }
    x1 := x1 + 0.5
    } 
    WinMove, ahk_exe throttle.exe,, 0, 0, %SetWidth%, %SetHeight%
    WinGetPos,,, winx, winy, %WinTitle%
    Sleep, 100
    WinMove, %WinTitle%,, (A_ScreenWidth/2)-(winx/2), (A_ScreenHeight/2)-(winy/2)
}
return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access global variables within a function you need to

add `global` within the function

```
CenterWindow(WinTitle){
    global
    WinGetPos,xx,yy, winx, winy, %WinTitle%
    x1 := xx + winx/2
    y1 := yy + winy/2
    loop 2
    { 
    y1 := yy + winy/2
        loop 2
        { 
            if ((A_ScreenWidth/2 = x1) && (A_ScreenHeight/2 = y1) && (winx := SetWidth) && (winy = SetHeight)) 
            {
                msgbox got em
            return
            }
            else
            y1 := y1 + 0.5
        }
    x1 := x1 + 0.5
    }
    WinMove, %WinTitle%,, 0, 0, SetWidth, SetHeight
    WinGetPos,,, winx, winy, %WinTitle%
    Sleep, 100
    WinMove, %WinTitle%,, (A_ScreenWidth/2)-(winx/2), (A_ScreenHeight/2)-(winy/2)
}
```

or declare the variables as super-global outside of the function (in the autoexecute section or within a hotkey/hotstring/or another function) by adding `global` before them:

```
global SetWidth := "1616"
global SetHeight := "939"
```

For more details read **[Local and Global Variables](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Functions.htm#Locals)**

Comment: Thanks! While I'm at it... Do you see any way that this function could be improved?

The basic idea is that when the game window is launched, the function checks to see if it's centered, and if it matches the resolution set in the global variables. If so, it does nothing. If not, it positions the window at 0,0, resizes it to the global variables, and then centers the window on the screen.